# CSS Stylesheet not linking to HTML first time web-dev

Tags: html, css

My CSS stylesheet is not linking to my HTML. I can't see any obvious issues yet but am a beginner at HTML (previous python knowledge) so please be nice, I'm sure there's an obvious mistake I'm making.

Have triple checked my code and also started from scratch creating a new HTML file.

This is the code with the link:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href="Styles/Styles1.css">
```

No error messages, just won't make changes on dev tools.

Comment: Does the Styles1.css file is in a different directory make sure path is correct

Comment: show the directory structure and more of the file.

Comment: we will need your directory structure

Comment: Good morning sister. Remember that S and s are different such that it may just be a case of case sensitivity

Comment: I believe `””` are different from `""`. Straight quotation marks are used, curly quotation marks are invalid/unrecognized. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57636266/7976244 answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct quotes, change from `”` to `"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Styles1.css">
```